# How early I can apply for the renewal of an Indian passport from a new city?

Tags: passports, india, passport-renewals

I will be moving to a new city to take up a job in 20 days. How soon I can apply for the renewal of my passport from the new place, after moving in there?

Can I use my rental agreement and HR letter as address proof?

Answer (score 1):

Your own government's instructions indicate you can apply as soon as you have the required proof:

[Change of Address](https://portal1.passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/online/faqServicesAvailable)

> Q61:   How do I change the address on my passport?
>   A:  To change the address in the passport, you have to apply for a "Re-issue" of passport and get the specified change done in the personal particulars.

[Table 3, found on page 11](https://portal1.passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/pdf/ApplicationformInstructionBooklet-V3.0.pdf)

> **Proof of Present Address.**
>   For Proof of Address attach one of the following documents:
>
> ```
> a. Water Bill
> b. Telephone (landline or postpaid mobile bill)
> c. Electricity bill
> d. Income Tax Assessment Order
> e. Election Commission Photo ID card
> f. Gas connection bill
> g. Certificate from Employer of reputed and widely known companies on letter 
>    head (Only public limited companies can give address proof on company 
>    letter head along with seal. Computerised print-outs shall not be 
>    entertained)
> h. Spouse’s passport copy (First and last page including family details 
>    mentioning applicant's name as spouse of the passport holder), (provided 
>    the applicant’s present address matches the address mentioned in the 
>    spouse’s passport)
> i. Parent’s passport copy, in case of minors (First and last page)
> j. Aadhaar Letter/ Card (Aadhaar letter/card or the e-Aadhaar (an 
>    electronically generated letter from the website of UIDAI), as the case 
>    may be, will be accepted as Proof of Address (POA) and Proof of Photo- 
>    Identity (POI) for availing passport related services. Acceptance of 
>    Aadhaar as PoA and PoI would be subject to successful validation with 
>    Aadhaar database.)
> k. Rent Agreement
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give details of all places you have stayed during past one year and the police verification would be done at all those places.

It will be better if you can get the passport reissued and police verification done at current address itself.